# Using absolute/relative positioning with css pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, css-position, positioning, pseudo-element

New to css here. A speech bubble using a span tag should be positioned relative to the parent divcontainer.

How can I achieve this without affecting the display of the pseudo element?

#### HTML (example):

```
<div id='divcontainer'> 
  <span> </span>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#divcontainer  { position: relative; }

span  {
    /* span tag shall be positioned relative to the div.*/
    position: relative;                
    left: 18px;
    top: -15px;
    
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

span:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 45%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 18px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: white;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

Any advice is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should apply absolute positioning to the child element.

```
#divcontainer {
    position: relative;
}
span {
    position: absolute;             
    left: 18px;
    top: -15px;
}
```

If an element has absolute [positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp), the element is positioned absolutely to its first positioned parent.
In your case, `#divcontainer` is the first positioned parent.

Comment: Will the pseudo element be affected as well? Is it going to be positioned relative to the span tag? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `position: absolute;` *both*  to the child element (`span`) *and*  to its pseudo element. The position of both will be in relation to the relatively positioned parent element and therefore also be relative to each other.

```css
#divcontainer
{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ddd;
}
span
{
    position: absolute;                
    left: 30px;
    top: 85px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;

}

span:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 45%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 18px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: white;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'divcontainer'> 
  <span>THE SPAN ELEMENT</span>
</div>
```